# Java not formatting scientific notation double

Tags: number-formatting, scientific-notation

I am trying to understand why java will not format a String representing a double with scientific notation:
My code:
  `public static void main(String... args)
  {
    System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", 2.898550724637681E-7));
  }`

This prints: 
`0.000000`

While i would expect `28985507.2463768`

The 'non scientific' decimal version is `28,985,507.24637681`

Comment: `2.898550724637681E-7` is `0.000000289855072463768`. You are telling it to print only six decimal places which are all 0's. You want `2.898550724637681E7`

Answer (score 0):

The number  2.898550724637681E-7 is actualy 0.0000002898550724637681. When you print with 6 decimals, the number is actualy 0.